# Memory leak warning on return

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

im working on a old code and i have this warning message:
Passed-by-value struct argument contains uninitialized data (e.g., via the field chain: 'origin.x'). If i could get dome help i would be very thankful :)

The code im using:

```
- (void)positionScroller
{
    CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect scrollerRect;

    if( self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
    {
        scrollerRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, screenFrame.size.width, screenFrame.size.height );
    }
    else if( self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    {
        scrollerRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, screenFrame.size.height, screenFrame.size.width );
    }

    _scroller.frame = scrollerRect;   <---This is where the compiler gives the warning
}
```

Best Regards.

Comment: ...and how is _scroller defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily get rid of the warning like this:

```
- (void)positionScroller 
{ 
    CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; 
    CGRect scrollerRect; 

    if( self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) 
    { 
        scrollerRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, screenFrame.size.width, screenFrame.size.height ); 
    } 
    else  
    { 
        scrollerRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, screenFrame.size.height, screenFrame.size.width ); 
    } 

    _scroller.frame = scrollerRect;   <---This is where the compiler gives the warning 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The thing is that the compiler can't be sure that one of the if/else-if blocks is ever reached, in which case, `scrollerRect` would still be uninitialized. You should either add a pure `else` statement or initialize `scrollerRect`, e.g. by setting it to `CGRectZero`.

By the way, this has nothing to do with a memory leak, it's more of a logic error.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared the CGRect

```
CGRect scrollerRect;
```

And you have assigned value to that after checking some conditions. If both of the conditions fail, then it will be without any value. So it is giving the warning. So add `else` condition and assign value to the `scrollerRect`.

So you can have

```
if( self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
{
    scrollerRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, screenFrame.size.width, screenFrame.size.height );
}
else if( self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
{
    scrollerRect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, screenFrame.size.height, screenFrame.size.width );
}
else
{
   scrollerRect = CGRectZero;
}
```